# Get data from inside script and pass it to plain text with php?

Tags: php, json, dom

Basically I want to get a data from inside the script tag from an external HTML page,

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("jwplayer");
    playerInstance.setup({
    id:'jwplayer',
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    aspectratio: "16:9",
    fullscreen: "true",
    primary: 'html5',
    provider: 'http',
    autostart: false,
    sources: [{"type":"video/mp4","label":360,"file":"MY-VIDEO-LINK"},{"type":"video/mp4","label":480,"file":"MY-VIDEO-LINK"}],
});
```

I just want the black-marked: >>
sources: **[{"type":"video/mp4","label":360,"file":"MY-VIDEO-LINK"},{"type":"video/mp4","label":480,"file":"MY-VIDEO-LINK"}]**

I have access to the page using PHP:
`$url = 'http://my-external-site.com/embed.php?url=blahblahblah';`

I've tried Curl, no luck, and DOM, almost there:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html($url);
$elem = $html->find('sources', 0); //tried with 'sources' but probably is wrong
echo $elem;
```

I'll appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following code without simple_html_dom . EDITED

```
$url = 'YOUR_URL';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);  //convert character asing
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    
$script = $xpath->query ('//script[contains(text(),"sources:")]')->item (0)->nodeValue;

$json = end(explode( 'sources:', $script));
$json = explode ( ']', $json)[0].']';

echo $json
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It's only returning `]` and takes some time to load.

Comment: is if you echo $script the result same as your javascript code?

Comment: can you share your url ? you can delete it after several minutes

Comment: It is in `$url` now.

Comment: One another question, how can I add `"default":true,` after `"label":360,`?

Comment: try use str replace function